# Not able to display Salesforce Lightning Error & Success Toast in Iphone (Salesforce1)

Tags: salesforce, apex

Is there any workaround to display error & success toast in iPhone SF1 app?

I have a quick action which opens a lightning component. I am displaying some error and success toast on the lightning button. It is working perfectly in android devices and desktop.

In iPhone app, the error toast is coming behind the component.

Answer (score 0):

In actions that open as a pop-up have a problem like you have. However, I have few suggestions to solve this problem;

If you don't have to display action(component) after showing pop-up errors or success messages, you can use below code in controller of component. For example;

```
 showMessageToast : function(message, type) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    if(toastEvent){
        toastEvent.setParams({
            title: "",
            message: message,
            type: type
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire(); //this code close action to display the error or success messages
    }
}
```

Another solution can be to show action new screen, not as pop-up. In this solution, you have to create new component and navigate this event with action. Therefore, your action will open in new screen.

One more option is that you can you detect users' device in component. For example, if user uses iphone, you can show error massages in the component using with aura:if.
Ex;

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isIPad == false}">
    //Some codes...
</aura:if>
```